# Run two docker compose with same static ip on a host

Tags: linux, networking, docker, docker-compose

I have a docker compose file like this:

```
version: '2'
services:
  app1:
    image: app
    networks:
       default:
           ipv4_address: 20.21.10.100
  app2:
    image: app
    networks:
        default:
            ipv4_address: 20.21.10.101
networks:
  default:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      config:
          - subnet: 20.21.10.0/24
```

It's ok when I am running 1 instance of this compose. but when I run another one it gave me this error:

```
ERROR: cannot create network 58610eba91b8ea064127ee6e58753bde6bc11af81ee05eccb815fd8dfc0e6688 (br-58610eba91b8): conflicts with network 43328a225317ee882853da87adc07df70158d6e2673335bceaf606465a1c6f5e (br-43328a225317): networks have overlapping IPv4
```

In fact I want my apps see each other with a specific ip in each group and this groups be isolated from each other.

I wonder if docker provides a solution for isolating networks from each other on a single host so two networks can have same subnet.

Comment: The error seems self-explanatory.   You can't have two networks with the same subnet.   Either move your network config up to to the daemon and dump the networks:, or make your second container have a different subnet.

Comment: I can't. the apps should see each other with that specific ip and I want to run 2 instances of this cluster on a host.

Comment: I don't believe this will be supported by docker. You should redesign your app to work off of hostnames "app1" and "app2" and let docker build the private bridge for each instance with unique ip's.

Comment: I dont see any other option, other than maybe running two VM's and two dockers (which seems really bad).   Fix the crappy app ;)

Comment: In fact  the app has a white list of IPs for accepting request.